# File not being sent via socket.io

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am using angularjs, nodejs and socketio for communication.

client html:

```
<div style='height: 0px;width: 0px; overflow:hidden;'>
    <input id="avatarInput" type="file" value="upload" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().upload(this)" />
</div>
<button data-ng-click="avatarButton()">Upload image</button>
```

client js:

```
$scope.avatarButton = function () {
    document.getElementById('avatarInput').click();
}
$scope.upload = function (file) {
    console.log('client: ' + file.type);
    socket.emit('image', {
        file: file
    });  
}
```

The above results in the output: `client: file` when I select a `.png` file to open.

server nodejs:

```
.on('image', function (data) {
    console.log('server: ' + data.file.type);
})
```

The above results in the output: `server: undefined`.

I'm guessing the file isn't being sent to the server correct via socket.io. i can't see the error here. More documentation here: http://socket.io/blog/introducing-socket-io-1-0/#binary

Quoted from the documentation:

> Socket.IO now supports emitting Buffer (from Node.JS), Blob,
>   ArrayBuffer and even File, as part of any datastructure:

**Working code:**

client html:

```
<div style='height: 0px;width: 0px; overflow:hidden;'>
    <input id="avatarInput" type="file" value="upload" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().upload(this.files)" />
</div>
<button data-ng-click="avatarButton()">Upload image</button>
```

client js:

```
    $scope.avatarButton = function () {
        document.getElementById('avatarInput').click();
    }
    $scope.upload = function (files) {
        if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
            socket.emit('uploadAvatar', {
                file: files[0]
            });
        } else {
            alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
        }
    }
```

server nodejs:

```
    .on('uploadAvatar', co.wrap(function* (data) {
        console.log(data.file); // spits out buffer
        var fs = require('fs');
        fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/public/avatar/myFile.png', data.file, {
            flag: "w"
        }, function (err) {
            if (err)
                return console.log(err);
            console.log("The file was saved!");
        });
    }))
```

Comment: `angular.element(this).scope().upload(this)` why are you doing this ?

Comment: @MartijnWelker It's a neat way of being able to style a `button` and make it act like a form/file input. Purely for show. It's a pain in the ass to style form file inputs for IE for example.

Comment: Shouldn't you use an instance of `FileReader` to send the blob?

Comment: @maurycy That is another possible way but socket.io states that you may send a `File` (if you read the documentation I linked). I am however starting to think they were referring to server-side only. Updated question with quote.

Comment: isn't the `file` argument in your function an object containing array `files` with a list of files?

Comment: @maurycy It *would* if I had the property `multiple` on the input. Otherwise I'm guessing `console.log('client: ' + file.type);` wouldn't of worked as I didn't select the element position. I'll double check.

Comment: the `file` is actually the input field that have the `files` atribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like this (see comments)

```
$scope.upload = function (element) { //element is an input[file]
    console.log('client: ' + element.files); //a FileList object that can be send
    socket.emit('image', {
        file: element.files //or element.files[0] depending of what you want to achieve
    });  
}
```

Comment: Indeed you were correct. I have no idea why I thought a single form file input was not encased in an array. Ta!

Comment: I think you will still have to create buffer/blob or fileReader to send the content of file to socket.io

Comment: It actually works flawlessly now (via sending the File, not a blob) :) I did a console.log on the file sent and true enough it is a buffer that comes out. Updated question with working code!